# yanking earlier kills not working

Tags: yank, kill-ring

I followed the tutorial verbatim and I am unable to yank earlier kills. I have looked online for support, but noone else seems to have this problem.

> Kill a line, move around, kill another line.
>      Then do C-y to get back the second killed line.
>      Then do M-y and it will be replaced by the first killed line.
>      Do more M-y's and see what you get.  Keep doing them until
>      the second kill line comes back, and then a few more.
>      If you like, you can try giving M-y positive and negative
>      arguments.

When I do C-y, I get back the last killed line. "Mark Set" shows up in the "command window"(where we type commands) after I do C-y. When I follow it up with M-y, **nothing happens**.

#### Question

My question is where do I start looking for the issues? Am I doing something wrong, or is the documentation not right? Could it be the version I have installed? Please help. Thanks.

#### computer specs:

- Emacs 24.3.1
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (almost up-to-date)

#### ME

I am a noob, going through line by line of the emacs tutorial to get the basics of emacs.

Comment: Reproduce the effect with `emacs -Q` (the command line option `-Q` prevents emacs from loading the personal init files). Cite here the exact emacs version that you get with `M-x emacs-version`. That is also a test whether you correctly interpret what key sequences like `M-x` or `M-y` mean (hold `Alt` and press `x`).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was trying to do what you were saying, when I realized M-x and M-y are my ubuntu shortcuts for some things. I checked how to override global shortcuts when emacs is opened, but it seems quite involved for now. I have changed the ubuntu shorcuts to something else for now. Can you tell me how I should proceed with this thread? Answer it or delete it? or mark as duplicate?

Comment: Judging from [the second off-topic item in the Section Asking of the help center](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the question is off-topic and should therefore be closed. Note, that the `magit` example on the referenced page is also an effect seen in emacs which turns out to be inflicted by a wrong configuration of `git`. But as mentioned there it **is** tricky. I will cast a closing-vote to draw the attention of moderators which will also state their opinion about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!  If you have only one line in the storage for kill (aka `kill-ring`), then nothing will happen on <kbd>M-y</kbd>.  Let's try an exercise to make this more visible:

1. Switch to the `*scratch*` buffer and add the following:

   ```
   Line one
   Line two
   Line three
   ```
2. Go back to the first line and hit <kbd>C-k</kbd> then <kbd>↓</kbd> three times.  (If we just hit <kbd>C-k</kbd> six times, it will be considered a single kill.)
3. Type `M-x describe-variable RET kill-ring RET`

I see the following (ignoring the documentation at the start):

```
Value: (#("Line three" 0 4
    (fontified t)
    4 10
    (fontified t))
  #("Line two" 0 4
    (fontified t)
    4 8
    (fontified t))
  #("Line one" 0 4
    (fontified t)
    4 8
    (fontified t)))
```

This shows the content of the kill-ring.  After <kbd>C-y</kbd>, <kbd>M-y</kbd> iterates over the contents of this variable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I wrote a comment earlier. which was: my global keyboard shortcuts coincided with emacs shortcuts. Once I changed them everything works as expected. Overriding global shortcuts seems quite involved so I am not checking it out now.